# count of substrings in column in excel

Tags: excel

I want to count all series of same elements in column - take a look at example:

```
A 
B 
B 
B 
A
A
C
C
A
A
```

for data above, result should be 5 - explanation:

```
A ] 1 
-------
B ]
B ] 2
B ]
-------
A ]
A ]3
-------
C ]
C ]4
-------
A ]
A ]5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series are in column A, for example from Row 1 to 15, use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A15<>A2:A16))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get your count would be to use a formula which returns `1` whenever the value of a row changes.  Assuming your letter data were in column `A`, beginning at row `1` (i.e. cell `A1`), I would enter the following formula into `B2`, and then copy it down the column:

```
= IF (A2 = A1, 0, 1)
```

Then just take the sum of the `B` column to get your answer.